# Starting app on wake up an android device

Tags: android, automation, wakeup

Hello Guys I need to start an android App when I wake up an Android Tv Box, Is it possible? I try with some automation app like Tasker,Macrodroid... but I don´t get It, only work if I turn off completly and make a complete start up.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [WakefulBroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver) that fires on device wake up or a BroadcastReceiver that fires after system successful boot.
More info about BroadcastReceivers can be found [Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts)

> **Note:** WakefulBroadcastReceiver was deprecated in API level 26.1.0.
>   As of Android O, background check restrictions make this class no longer generally useful. (It is generally not safe to start a service from the receipt of a broadcast, because you don't have any guarantees that your app is in the foreground at this point and thus allowed to do so.) Instead, developers should use android.app.job.JobScheduler to schedule a job, and this does not require that the app hold a wake lock while doing so (the system will take care of holding a wake lock for the job).